# How to get the %cpu of a process in FreeBSD?

Tags: cpu-usage, freebsd, ps

In Linux, the %cpu returned by the ps command is documented as *"cpu utilization of the process in "##.#" format.  Currently, it is the CPU time used divided by the time the process has been running (cputime/realtime ratio), expressed as a percentage."* So it's the  %cpu utilization over the entire lifetime of the process. Not so useful.

But in FreeBSD, the %cpu returned by the ps command is documented as *"The CPU utilization of the process; this is a decaying average over up to a minute of previous (real) time."*

It's easy to get this %cpu by running the command `ps -p $$ -o %cpu`, but is there a way to read this information **without spinning up a sub-process?** Something like reading a /proc/ entry or a syscall?

Comment: `getrusage` is what you're looking for. Probably cheaper than parsing a /proc file.

Comment: It doesn't seem so; the `ru_utime` field has the total user CPU time of the process, but not FreeBSD's 1-minute decaying average.

Comment: You have to take two measurements and call `gettimeofday` before or after each. That will give you a reasonable utilization wrt a single CPU. Then you get to decide how often you want to save that information. But I've never ever needed cpu utilization for a traced process. All I've ever needed is cpu seconds consumed wrt to the other measures that drive cpu consumption.